# VoiceOver does not read website on iPhone (Safari or Chrome)

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, accessibility, voiceover

We can't get our website to be read on iPhones with VoiceOver on Safari neither Chrome. It works fine on MacOS with VoiceOver and also on Android with Talkback.

The website is https://preprod.vhelp.co.uk

Could it be that we need to do a separate set up for iOS? Other websites work normal on the same iPhone phones and Safari. (So it is not about configuration on the device)

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble with iOS too.  My best guess is that your `aria-hidden="true"` elements are not properly setting `aria-hidden="false"` when unhidden.

(**Note** that a "false" value of `aria-hidden` might not be fully supported.  See the [second note](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#h-note-43) under the `aria-hidden` spec.  It's better to delete the `aria-hidden` attribute rather than set its value to "false".)

I found 47 occurrences of `aria-hidden` on the page, mainly to support responsive view but the responsive/mobile view can be seen on the desktop if you bump your font up about 170% (depending on your browser size).  So you might be able to mimic the same unreadable version by hitting <kbd>cmd++</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to get to 200%.  It might make it easier to debug.